# moment generating function find distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_i\sim U(0, 1)$, where $i = 1,\ldots,n$ and where all random variables are independent. Determine using the moment generating function (mgf) the distribution of the random variable $Y$

$$
Y = -2\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right).
$$

I know that in the case variables are independent and they're added together as to form a new variable. The new variable's moment generating function is just the product of the two old variables' mgfs but what confuse me here is that we're inside of the logarithm and I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: you have log of product which is just a sum of logs, then you can use what you know, since $\ln(X_k)$ are independent, too

Comment: [Spoiler alert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method).

Comment: @DominikKutek : Since you're going to exponentiate in order to get the moment-generating function, I don't think that's the best way to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
M_Y(t) & = \operatorname E(e^{tY}) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E\left( e^{-2t\ln\prod_{i=1}^n X_i} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E\left(\left( e^{\ln\prod_{i=1}^n X_i} \right)^{-2t} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E\left( \left( \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^{-2t} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E \left( \prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{-2t} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \prod_{i=1}^n \operatorname E(X_i^{-2t}) \text{ by independence} \\[8pt]
& = \left( \operatorname E\left(X_1^{-2t}\right) \right)^n \text{ by identical distribution}.
\end{align}

Comment: What happened to the $t$?

Comment: @Math1000 : Momentary distraction. (No pun intended.)

Comment: Okay, so how do we recognize a distribution from this expression? I compute $$\mathbb E[X_1^{-2t}] = \int_0^1 x^{-2t} = 1-2t, $$
so
$M_Y(t) = (1-2t)^n$. So this is just a $\chi^2$ distribution?

Comment: @Math1000 : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $-2\ln X_1$ has an exponential distribution with expected value $2,$ and that is a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: For $x\ge0$ we have
$$ \begin{align} & \Pr(-2\ln X \le x) \\ {} \\ = {} & \Pr( X \ge e^{-x/2}) \\ {} \\ = {} & 1 - e^{-x/2}, \end{align} $$ so that is an exponential distribution with expected value $2,$ and therefore a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom. $\qquad$

Comment: When the number of degrees of freedom is anything besides $2,$ the chi-square distribution is not an exponential distribution. It is a gamma distribution (regardless of whether $\text{d.f.}=2$ or not). $\qquad$

Comment: Oops, left off the $\mathsf dx$ in my integral. But it seems the meaning got across.

Comment: A subtler point here is whether the chi-square distribution is determined by its moments. Some distributions are not. For example, there is a distribution that has the same moments, and thus the same moment-generating function, as the lognormal distribution, but is nonetheless a different distribution, not a lognormal. But some distributions are determined by their moments, and so do not share the same moment-generating function with any other distribution.

Comment: @Math1000 or others How did you get $1-2t$? I get $\frac{1}{1-2t}$. Thanks.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @hotzjacobb You are correct, it is $(1-2t)^{-1}$. However the moment-generating function of a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is $(1-2t)^{-k/2}$, so our result $(1-2t)^{-n}$ is still the moment-generating function of a $\chi^2$ distribution. Thank you for pointing out the error.